# Compiling Qt using visual studio command prompt

Tags: visual-studio, qt, mingw

if I follow [this link](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/02/01/how-to-compile-qt-4-7-with-visual-studio-2010/)
and build qt libraries using visual studio command prompt does the output binaries is using mingw or microsoft c++ compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting binaries should be used with the visual studio compiler.

This process seems unnecessary since Qt has posted built binaries for the latest versions of Qt built for VS 2010:

http://qt-project.org/downloads

[Qt libraries 4.8.3 for Windows (VS 2010, 235 MB)](http://releases.qt-project.org/qt4/source/qt-win-opensource-4.8.3-vs2010.exe)

Comment: True, though those are not necessarily configured with all the options you might want. In general they are good though.

Comment: those binaries are for visual studio compiler  are 32bit or 64bit ?